# Проблемы с удалением динамического массива типа char в классе

Tags: c++, visual-studio

На этапе компиляции ошибок нет. На этапе выполнения программного кода появляется окно с сообщением которое ссылается на строку 'delete[] str;'. Как решить данного рода проблему?

```
class MyString {
private:
    static const int size0 = 80;
    char* str;
    int size1 = 0;
public:
    MyString() {
        str = new char[size0];
    }
    MyString(int uSize0) {
        str = new char[uSize0];
    }
    MyString(char uStr[]) {
        for (int a = 0; uStr[a] != '\0'; a++) {
            size1++;
        }
        str = new char[size1];
        strcpy(str, uStr);
    }
    ~MyString() { }
    void input(char uStr[]) {
        delete[] str;
        for (int a = 0; uStr[a] != '\0'; a++) {
            size1++;
        }
        str = new char[size1];
        strcpy(str, uStr);
    }
    void show() {
        std::cout << "\n\n You String: " << str << "\n\n";
    }
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А можете показать код в котором вы используете ваш класс? Просто такой код вполне работает `int main() { MyString str = "qwe"; str.show(); }`

Comment: У вас нету конструктора копирования, скорее всего проблема в этом. Но да, покажите код.

Comment: А ещё вы не устанавливаете `size1`  в двух конструкторах.

Comment: Чето я затупил и забыл использовать единственную функцию, где есть `delete`. Но такой пример тоже работает: int main() { MyString str = "qwe"; str.input("qwerty"); str.show(); }

Comment: int main() {
 MyString str0("Nikita Big");
 str0.show();
 str0.input("Nikita litl");
 str0.show();
 return 0;
}

Ситуация связанна методом input(). Если этого метода нет, нет и всплывающего окна.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У Вас два метода портят кучу, причём делают это одинаково:

```
MyString(char uStr[]) {
        for (int a = 0; uStr[a] != '\0'; a++) {
            size1++;
        }
        str = new char[size1];
        strcpy(str, uStr);
    }
```

и

```
void input(char uStr[]) {
        delete[] str;
        for (int a = 0; uStr[a] != '\0'; a++) {
            size1++;
        }
        str = new char[size1];
        strcpy(str, uStr);
    }
```

`strcpy` копирует все символы,пока не встретит нуль символ, из одного указателя в другой. При этом копирование включает нуль символ. Но Ваш доморощённый `strlen` не включает нуль символ(что правильно), поэтому этот факт нужно учесть при выделение строки. Таким образом выделение памяти под строку, в обоих случаях должно выглядеть именно так:

```
str = new char[size1 + 1];
```

Comment: Там ещё дикая куча всего по коду. Например, `size1` не обнуляется в начале функции `input`.

Comment: @VladD, ага, ну с чего-то надо начинать. Его текущая ошибка явно в том, что я описал. Будет писать дальше, получит больше ошибок. Хотя там московский Влад порасписал его ошибки, может учтёт.

Answer (score 3):

Когда класс содержит указатель на динамически выделенную память, то вам необходимо обеспечить в явном виде по крайней мере конструктор копирования, копирующий оператор присваивания и деструктор. Иначе может оказаться. что два объекта класса в результате копирования или присваивания будут содержать указатели на одну и ту же область памяти, для которой будет осуществлена попытка ее удалить дважды каждым объектом.

Кроме того член класса `size1` во многих случаях у вас не отражает длину хранящейся строки, так как ему не присваивается никакого значения. И вы забываете выделять память для завершающего нуля копируемых строк.

Также конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор с целочисленным параметром не инициализируют выделенную память. При выводе таких строк с помощью метода `show` возникнет неопределенное поведение программы.

Поэтому нет никакого смысла иметь статический член класса `size0` равным `80`. По умолчанию у вас должна быть пустая строка.

Также деструктор у вас не удаляет выделенную строку.

В методе `input` вы увеличиваете размер текущей строки вместо того, чтобы сделать его равным длине строки параметра

```
  for (int a = 0; uStr[a] != '\0'; a++) {
        size1++;
```

Здесь член класса `size1` не был изначально установлен в 0.

Обратите внимание, что лучше, когда длина строки имеет тип `size_t` так как именно этот тип имеет возвращаемое значение оператора `sizeof` и функции работы со строками `std::strlen`.

Класс может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
class MyString {
private:
    size_t n;
    char *s;
public:
    MyString() : n( 0 ), s( new char[1] ) {
        MyString::s[0] = '\0';
    }
    MyString( const char *s ) : n( 0 ) {
        while ( s[n] != '\0' ) ++n;
        MyString::s = new char[MyString::n + 1];
        std::strcpy( MyString::s, s );
    }

    MyString( const MyString &rhs ) : n( rhs.n ), s( new char[n + 1] ) {
        std::strcpy( MyString::s, rhs.s );
    }

    ~MyString() { delete [] MyString::s; }

    MyString & operator =( const MyString &rhs ) {
        if ( this != &rhs ) {
            if ( MyString::n != rhs.n ) {
                delete [] MyString::s;
                MyString::n = rhs.n;
                MyString::s = new char[n + 1];
            }
            std::strcpy( MyString::s, rhs.s );
        }

        return *this;
    }

    size_t size() const { return MyString::n; }

    void input( const char *s ) {
        size_t i = 0;
        while ( s[i] != '\0' ) ++i;
        if ( MyString::n != i ) {
            delete [] MyString::s;
            MyString::n = i;
            MyString::s = new char[MyString::n + 1];
        }
        std::strcpy( MyString::s, s );
    }
    void show() const {
        std::cout << "\n\n You String: " << MyString::s << "\n\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!